# Serve static react app with nodejs through docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have directories for node and react like this:

```
Project
 + client
   + admin
      + build
          + index.html
 + server_api
   + server.js
   + Dockerfile
 
 + docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose file**

```
  server_api:
    container_name: speed_react_server_api
    build:
        context: ./server_api
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: speed_react/server_api
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - ./server_api:/usr/src/app
```

My server.js serve static file from react app like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/admin/', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

But it seems that it is not working.
I do not want to move folder `client` to `server`

Can you suggest me solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange files as needed in your `Dockerfile`.

Note that this will require removing the `volumes:` line that (probably) causes your entire Dockerfile to get mostly ignored.  Your Docker container won't be usable as a development environment.  A host Node is very easy to install and features like live reloading and interactive debugging will work much better with much less configuration and tuning required.

If you move the `Dockerfile` up to the root directory, it can access both directory trees.  Then you can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to build the client and then copy it into the server.  That would roughly look like this:

```sh
FROM node:14 AS client
WORKDIR /app
COPY client/package.json client/yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
COPY client .
RUN yarn build

FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY server_api/package.json server_api/yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
COPY server_api .
COPY --from=client /app/admin/build admin  # <-----
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

In your code, change the path to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'admin', 'index.html')`; it should match the destination inside the container filesystem of the `COPY --from=client` line.

In your host development environment, you can use a symbolic link to point at the files (on MacOS or Linux)

```sh
ln -s ../client/admin/build admin
```

Finally, you need to change your `docker-compose.yml` to point at the root directory as the build context, and remove the bind mount (which will have a dangling symlink and not the file content).

```yaml
server_api:
  build: .
  image: speed_react/server_api
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

One answer is given by @David, that best to build the Docker image with multi-stage.

The other way is to build the only API and as the client has no dependency and so you can just mount `clinet with API`.

```
  server_api:
    container_name: speed_react_server_api
    image: abc
    ports:
        - "4001:4001"
    entrypoint: sh -c "cd /usr/src/app/server_api/; node server.js"
    volumes:
        - ./server_api/:/usr/src/app/server_api/
        - ./client/:/usr/src/app/client/
```

---

You did not mention the error but I assume the script not serving the distribution.

But seems like you are missing [express-static-files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) configuration.

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the >`express.static` built-in middleware function in Express.

The function signature is:

```
express.static(root, [options])
```

Here is the complete script

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const PORT=process.env.PORT | 4001
app.use(express.static('../client/admin/build/dist', {
  maxAge: '31557600' 
}))

var compress = require('compression');
app.use(compress()); 

app.use('/', express.static('../client/admin/build/dist/', { redirect: false }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/admin/build/dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Incentive frontend is listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but You might misunderstood my question. 
Due to react app is not in folder of Dockerfile so server.js cannot read it.
I want a solution for this. 
If react app in folder of node, it is running well.

Comment: oh got it, one answer was in mind already give by @David, updating answer for another approch.